# How to reduce time of listing files in a directory in which files are being added continously

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to filter files in a directory using a FileFilter (based on date modification). Files are continuously being added to this directory.
I am using Threadpool executor to process each file returned by FileFilter accept() method.

But the time taken to list all the files in this directory is large which slows down the completion time of my code. This is due to files being continuously added in the directory.

Is there any other way where files can be listed much faster. Please note that I need files which have been modified before a certain modification time and this is being checked through FileFilter.

```
final ThreadPoolExecutor executor = poolFactory.getExecutor();
    FileFilter fileFIlter = new FileFilter() {

          @Override
          public boolean accept(File file) {

            if (file.getName().toUpperCase().contains(fileNameFilter) &&
                null != startDate && file.lastModified() >= startDate.getTime() &&
                null != endDate && file.lastModified() <= endDate.getTime()
                ) {

              executor.execute(new FileFinder(file, textFinder));

              return true;
            }
            return false;
          }
        };

        file.listFiles(fileFIlter);
```

Comment: Note that I have also tried IOFileFilter API (AgeFileFilter) of Apache commons IO but the results are same.

Comment: Use the NIO2 watch service.

Comment: Many operating systems perform poorly when the number of files in a directory gets large. Solution: put less files in the directory. For example, create a subdirectory for the first letter of the filename, or even two levels of subdirectories for the first two letters of the file name.

Comment: Actually, this directory is on some other network and creating sub directory is not an option in this case. The program gives result quickly as soon as no more files are being added in the directory, which happens rarely.

Comment: As far as I know, use of NIO2 watch service will notify any modification in a directory. But in my case, there are number of files which are already there in the directory, when i run my program. And the program has to work on those files which have already been added in the directory and filter out those which are being added. Can the watch service help me in this case? please suggest.

Comment: You shouldn't use a shared drive or folder in  an application for any reason whatsoever, let alone scanning a remote directory for files to process. Everything about it is bad, from performance to failure modes. Rethink: redesign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no faster way to read a directory.  And it is not a Java issue.  Simply put, the operating system only "indexes" a directory by name.  Any other form of lookup / query needs to be implemented by iterating all entries, one at a time, and retrieving and testing the file attributes.

The only way you are going to do better than that is if you do a first scan of the directory (on application startup), and then use the file watcher service to look for any changes.  The first scan takes just as long as currently, but using the file watcher avoids repeatedly re-scanning.

If that doesn't work for you, then you are going to need to manage your files differently.  For example:

- Maybe you could use `File.rename` to move files to another directory once you have processed them.
- Maybe you could append the incoming information to the end of an existing file rather than creating new files.
- Maybe you could put the information (straight) into a database and do away with the need for an intermediate file.

---

And if you can't do any of the above, then sorry but there is no way to make it go faster.